# Batch Help -- Move File To Directory, If Exist Filename, Rename 001

Tags: scripting, batch-file, cmd

I have a batch file that checks a root directory every 10 seconds for PDF files and copies those files to their corresponding subfolders of the exact same name.

What I'm missing is that I need my batch file to check the target subdirectory for the named file, and if the named file exists, to rename the new file to be copied to `!filename!001.pdf` and have the `001` get incremented as duplicate file names are copied. Here's what I got:

```
    :loop
    setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
    cls

    pushd c:\files\

    for /f "tokens=*" %%1 in ('dir /a-d /b c:\files\*.pdf') do (
    set filename=%%~n1&set dirname=!filename:~0,7!

    dir c:\files /b *.pdf > location1list.tmp
    for /f %%a in (location1list.tmp) do dir c:\files\%%a > location2list.tmp

    if not exist c:\files\!dirname! (md c:\files\!dirname!)
    move %%1 c:\files\!dirname!\>nul
    ) 
    timeout /t 10
    goto:loop
```

Any suggestions how I can get the files renamed?

I.e. if `Bob.pdf` exists in the `Bob` folder and another `Bob.pdf` is added to the `C:\files` folder, I want it to be copied to the `C:\files\bob` folder as `Bob001.pdf`.

Comment: Sounds to me like you're trying to invent a [revision control system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Revision_control). I'd strongly recommend to use an existing RCS instead (e.g. [Subversion](http://subversion.apache.org/), [Mercurial](http://mercurial.selenic.com/), [git](http://git-scm.com/), ...).

Comment: This isn't for a website. My client has an old scanner that has no standalone networking capabilities. It scans files and drops the PDFs into a root directory, and my client wants the files the users scan to go to their home directories instead of in the general folder. The scanner cannot distinguish the difference between users, but it does provide the option of naming scans. I instructed everyone to name their scans after their first name and the batch to do the organizing. Only problem is that the current code moves the PDFs, but overwrites if the same named PDF exists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this should do what you want.  May need some tweaking.  Also I have not tested it, just wrote it from memory.  Need any explanations, just ask.

**Script**

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion
pushd C:\files

:Main
for /f "tokens=*" %%A in ('dir /a-d /b *.pdf') do (
    if not exist "%%~dpnA\*" md "%%~nA"
    set "File=%%~dpnA\%%~nxA"
    if exist "!File!" call :Name "!File!" File
    echo !File!
    move "%%~fA" "!File!"
)
goto Wait

:Name <Target> <Variable>
set "Count=0"
:Count
set /a "Count+=1"
set "Number=00%Count%"
if exist "%~dpn1%Number:~-3%%~x1" goto Count
set "%~2=%~dpn1%Number:~-3%%~x1"
goto :eof

:Wait
timeout /t 10
goto Main

:End
popd
endlocal
```

**Limitations**

1. Each target subdirectory can only handle a maximum of 1000 files as this is written.  If the subdirectory hits this maximum then the script will get stuck in an infinite loop.

**Update**

Fixed an error in my initial script

Comment: Thanks for your help David. Running your script returned without any syntax errors, but the files were once again merely copied and overwritten -- precisely the result with my listed script. I appreciate your suggestion/contribution.

Comment: I just looked at it again and it seems that your code attempts not to rename the file, but to create a new directory. The cmd prompt shows that instead of renaming the file, it tries to create an additional subdirectory named  001. I tried it with filename  Bob.pdf. One of the IF statements came back like this:

  if exist "C:\Files\Bob\001" goto Count

Comment: @Brandon  I believe I have fixed it.  I was improperly setting the Name variable to begin with.  It should work now.

Comment: @Brandon  The script works as follows.  1. List all the pdf files in the C:\files directory  2. For each file, verify it has a subdirectory, if it does not, create one  3. Check if a file with the same name already exists, if so call the name function  4.  The name function will loop from 1 to 999 until it finds a file that does not exist.  5. Use the new name to move the file.

Comment: Works like a charm. Greatly appreciated David. I wish I can say I came out of this learning something, but I seem to be a bit more bewildered than I was coming in. Perhaps the purchase of "Batch Scripting for Dummies" is at hand. Thanks again!

Comment: @Brandon  No books needed, There are some great free online resources to get you going.  SS64.com ,  RobVanderWoude.com ,  DosTips.com ,  and TechNet ( http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc772390(v=ws.10).aspx )

Comment: Indeed you did.  And no apologies necessary.  Welcome to S.O.!